# How to install package in live server without shell command?

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I have my laravel running in server. Now I need to install the package in that live server but i don't have shell permission. How can i install package without using command.

i have already tried uploading "vendor" file and update composer.json from local but still i cant use package throwing error "not found"

Comment: upload  all files that run in local

Comment: every time? 
what is an alternative?